# Load specific XML content to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I'm trying to load specific content from a XML to a HTML div. I'm using a function with parameters to do this.

This my call to function:

```
loadDoc("news.xml","destak-article","article");
```

this should send a request for the xml file, get the content of «article» tag and put it on the «destak-article» div.

Here's my function body:

```
function loadDoc(url,id,tagname){

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // code for IE6, IE5
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(tagname)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work.
On Chrome js console I get this error:

```
Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null
```

On Firebug I get:

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(tagname)[0] is undefined
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does the server response with content type "text/xml"? If you open the document directly in the browser does it indicate the xml markup is bad in any way?

Comment: Indeed I had some errors on my XML. Some elements that were showing the wrong way. -.- It works now. Got to study more XML. Thanks Marth for the solution and everyone for the replies.

Answer (score 1):

Did you verify the server response? Use some error checking in your code. For example:

```
if (xmlhttp.status == 200) { 
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(tagname)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
else {
 alert('error');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register a handler function that will be called once the request is complete.  You can see an [example of how to do that here.](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#introduction)

What's happening in your case is that you're trying to get the `xmlDoc` immediately after sending the request and the server hasn't had time to process the request and respond yet.

Comment: He is doing a synchronous call - that is the third argument to xmlhttp.open set to false.